# Uneven looping and iteration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am a beginner in MATLAB and I am encountering the following problem.
I am trying to write a code that will run the x first then after each 4 runs, k increments by 1. I have searched for the solution, but could not find one.

```
a=[1;2;3;4];
b=[8;4;6;7];
k=[7;4;5;6;7;8;9];
for i = 1:1:4
    for j = 1:1:7
       m=a[i]+ b[i]*k[j]
    end
end
```

---

my equation is M=a(x)+b(x)*k(t)
where x=1:4 and t=1:7

Like :

1+8*7

2+4*7

3+6*7

4+7*7

Then

1+8*4

2+4*4
.
.
.

and so on.

Can anyone please help on this? Thank you

Comment: The loop with variable `j` should come before  the loop with the variable `i`. (you should be using some other variable names though)

Comment: Hi Sardar Usama, the code works. Thanks heaps Cheers. Below is the correct one.
a=[1;2;3;4];
b=[8;4;6;7];
k=[7;4;5;6;7;8;9];
for j = 1:1:7
    for i = 1:1:4
       m=a(i)+ b(i)*k(j)
    end
end

Comment: @Sunshine.C if you have a working answer, can you post it as an answer and accept it so that this questions can be identified as 'answered'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code I have. Thank you again for the help.

```
a=[1;2;3;4];
b=[8;4;6;7];
k=[7;4;5;6;7;8;9];
for j = 1:1:7
    for i = 1:1:4
        m=a(i)+ b(i)*k(j)
    end
end
```

Kind regards